# jQuery Mobile: Can't handle the correct event once a page changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an application which simply changing between few URLs (I am using $.mobile.changePage method to change between them):

1. index.html#page1
2. index.html#page2

Anyway, the transitions seems to work fine, but my main problem is that I am less familiar with jQuery Mobile. After reading a lot around, either in the API or different posts, I am still not sure **how can I simply alert each time each of the "pages" loads?**

I have tried using pageinit, mobileinit, document.ready and such and still wasn't able to solve this.

Comment: events that fire once (ascending order): `pagebeforechange`, `pagebeforecreate`, `pagecreate`, `pageinit`. events that fire continuously: `pagebeforehide`, `pagehide`, `pagebeforeshow`, `pageshow`, `pagechange`. Question: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: i only want to put a simple alert once a page is changed. but only on that page. that's it. and of course if u keep navigating to this page, every time it will alert. all of my attempts makes my app fire any of these events only one time only.

Comment: Check this simplified details about page events http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/ what version are you using?

Comment: It does explain well few things but i must admit this is hard to grasp. In practice, I keep asking myself a lot of questions, for example: if i would like to check if a user is logged against my db, what would be the right event? (considering the fact i don't want him to access pages before i check him against db. and also, when would i use document.ready?

Comment: im using jquery.mobile-1.4.2

Comment: You'll need `pagebeforechange` event.

Answer (score 0):

upfront - http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/  - is deprecated, so consider updating.  At any rate - use this :https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/

(from jquery mobile)

```
jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "pagechange", function( event ) { ... } )
```

Comment: Could u clarify why do u have to do it on a certain selector?
I am not sure that is what i need, i would like to set a certain behavior for each page, where does it take place ?

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/   -- specifically "Programmatically change from one page to another. This method is used internally for the page loading and transitioning that occurs as a result of clicking a link or submitting a form, when those features are enabled."  - https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/  : "Description: This event is triggered after the changePage() request has finished loading the page into the DOM and all page transition animations have completed."

Comment: as ive mentioned above, i know how to use the changepage, which actually doing the transition ok. what im trying to do is once the page has been changed, to pop an alert for this minified example. it seems like the on binding is not working like i thought..

Comment: I have tried $(document).bind('pagechange', '#page-name', function (event) { alert('a') }); which is firing on every page change.

Comment: so it's working? You'll need to handle the event appropriately for whatever you are trying to accomplish. If you are looking for specific pageloads, then create that filter logic and tie it to the event handler

Comment: no, im still trying to figure out whats my problem. as ive explained i only want to put a simple alert once a page is changed. but only on that page. that's it. and of course if u keep navigating to this page, every time it will alert.